Infimum of a Set $A = \{ n - \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \} $
I have had trouble proving that the infimum of the set $A = \{ n - \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \} $ is zero.
It is easy to prove that 0 is a lower bound. What I am struggling with is proving the following statement:
Statement: For every positive $\epsilon$, there exists $a \in A$ such that $a < \epsilon + 0$ .
How can I find such an element in the set?
What I have tried is using the Archimedean property to find such an element, but I have not been successful:
Since $\epsilon > 0$ , by the Archimedean property, there exists $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$. Then, $ -\epsilon < -\frac{1}{n} $, so $ n - \epsilon < n - \frac{1}{n} $, which is not what I want.

Pick $a = 1-\frac 11$?

The sequence is strictly increasing, so $n=1$ yields the smallest element.

Oh of course, but if I had only asked: "For every positive real number, is there an element of the form $ n - \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon $? How can I find such an element? Zero always works, but a more optimal element, for example, for  $\epsilon = 2$ , $ 2 - \frac{1}{2} $ works, and for $ \epsilon = 5 $ , $ 5 - \frac{1}{5} $ works. I need an element not as trivial as zero. Just out of curiosity (and without using convergence)

the only element that works for small enough $\varepsilon$ is zero, just plug in a few values of $n$ to see how the sequence behaves. The definition of infimum/supremum doesn't say anything about "optimality". We are required for every $\varepsilon$ to pick a suitable element, that's it.

For a given positive $\epsilon$, this is an inequality to be solved: $$\begin{align*}n-\frac1n &< \epsilon\
n^2 - \epsilon n - 1 &< 0
\end{align*}$$together with $n \in \mathbb N$.

As others said, you can always pick $1-\frac11=0$. In fact, if $n\neq1$, then
$$n-\frac1n\ge2-\frac12=\frac32$$
So for any $\varepsilon<3/2$, you have to pick $n=1$.
Hope this helps. :)

$0$ is an element of the set, and is also the lower bound of the set, so it is the minimum of the set. If a set has a minimum, it is also always the infimum.
